# I want to delete users from a group in Active Directory

Tags: powershell

I have a created a custom power shell activity to delete users from a group in A.D.
In the execution command i have given the code like,

Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Cab-Approval" -Members Williams,James.Anderson,Jaffer.Hamzad
So, when i clikced on Test Inputs it is giving error like,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpyMl.png)

SO what is this error, and how to over come this. Can some one help me here

Regards,
Vijay

Comment: Provide some code example, paste error contents instead an image.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to read the FAQs on how to format your questions. Posting an image is discouraged as we're not able to easily digest it as oppose to pre-formated code blocks. A link to the FAQ for asking is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta)

That said, it looks like from your error message that you're either running the script remotely or running it from a non-interactive shell. The reason you're receiving this error is because Remove-ADGroupMember prompts you for an `Are you sure?` response.

You can do the following to mitigate this:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "Cab-Approval" -Members Williams,James.Anderson,Jaffer.Hamzad -Force
```

The `-Force` switch will ignore the prompts.

Comment: A peek at Vijay's activity suggest their question's downvotes, close clicks and/or negative comment led Vijay to give up on SO before you had published your answer. Perhaps, if a newcomer's question gets even a single downvote or close vote, then *immediately* automatically post a bot comment saying (a much better version of) "We apologize for any unduly negative response Vijay. We've queued your question for review; please be patient with us. In the meantime, please, responders, BE NICE!". (My comment arguably belongs on meta, not here, but I mean it as a comment to you personally.)